# .htaccess redirect to page from inaccessible directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What Im trying to do is redirect any invalid url after a certain directory if it doesn't exist.

For example if I went to http://www.foobar.com/testapi/users/frank

the directory frank does not exist, but I would like it to go to the index of /users

I want it so that no matter what I type or / after users I want it to go to the under at users.

I figured it would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^testapi/users/(.*)$ ^testapi/users [QSA]
```

Being that the api is not on the root of the url and its at /testapi would I also have to do

```
RewriteBase /testapi
```

Comment: It might be simpler to simply redefine your 404 (error) to a page that is a redirect to your chosen directory.

Comment: I need it to be this way so that no matter what I put after /users like /users/all/frank, I want it to go to /users/index.php

Comment: Right. So in the `.htaccess` file under `/users`, add `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404-redirect.html`, or `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php` or whatever, and within that file, create a *redirect*, something like (if it were cgi) `print "Location: http://www.sum.place/users/index.php\n\n";`

Comment: Would this allow me to keep the url they type intact? so that I can parse the url after the redirect? I want it to go to a different page but I want to capture the url they typed in with php.

Comment: You would find the request in your log(s). My suggestion simply turns a `404` (error) into a `301` (redirect). I might add, if it helps, that for PHP you could use `header(Location: /users/index.php);` as `404-redirect.php` as mentioned/suggested above.